# reversing the order of this double integral in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Lets say I want to find the area of this shape:

[image]

One way which works in giving the correct area is the following:

$dA=rd\theta dr$

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2Rsin\theta }rdrd\theta$

I can visualise this as first creating a line of  length $2Rsin\theta $ and then sweeping it over $\pi $ rads to give the full area.

However if i were to first integrate over $\theta $(reverse the order) what would my new limits be? I tried $\int_{0}^{2R}\int_{0}^{arcsin(r/2R) }rd\theta dr$. But it does not give me the same answer.

What are the right limits if integrating over $d\theta$ first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the integration region in the $\theta - r$ plane you will see that inverting the order of integration leads to
$$
\int_0^{2R} \int_{\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)}^{\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)} r \, d\theta dr
$$

You need to consider different branches of $\arcsin$ when you cross $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be

$$\int _0^{2 R}\int _{\pi -\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2 R}\right)}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2 R}\right)}r\,d\theta\,dr=R^2\,\pi$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are computing two integrals? If you draw the integration region in $\theta -  r$ axis you can clearly consider a single integration region. In fact, you are choosing the complement of that region over the rectangle $[0 , \pi] \times [0, 2R]$.

Comment: Yes, it's a mistake. In fact, I considered the complementary region. Corrected !!

Comment: Curiously, the value of the integral is indeed the same!